# How to check if file exists in media folder?

Tags: django, django-templates

Here I successfully uploaded files in database(working fine). The issue here is file is stored in the database and if in case the media folder gets deleted it will raise an error `[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: ...` So my question is how can I handle this error.

If the file is in database but not in the media folder then I want to handle this error and display the template without error. How can I do this ?

template

```
{% for document in documents %}
 <tr>
<td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
 <td>{{document.filename|truncatechars:15}}</td>
 <td>{{document.file.size|filesizeformat}}</td>
 <td>{{document.category}}</td>
 <td>{{document.file.url}}</td>
<tr>
{% endfor %}
```

models

```
class Document(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(DocumentCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='media/',
                            validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['pdf', 'xlsx', 'pptx', 'docx','xls']), file_size])
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    @property
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use default_storage.exists(path) to determine that.

```
 from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
 path = 'path/to/file'
 default_storage.exists(path)
```

But notice that your path must be in the project folder.

if the file exists in the path then the function returns True otherwise False

and there is a path attribute in the Django `FileFeild` to get path.

Answer (score 0):

1. Django is not supposed to serve media files on prod, so additional code related to **reading** regular media files makes not much sense
2. `self.file.name` contains path **relative** to MEDIA_ROOT, so implemented approach is not really correct
3. since you know about `os.path` it's not clear what you're actually asking about; there is `path.exists` method, and more specific `os.path.isfile`
4. exceptions can be catched by `try-except` block as any other exceptions in python.

```
    try:
        # Do something with the file
    except IOError:
        # Do something in case of error
```